# How does mongoDB performs bulk writes efficiently?

Tags: json, mongodb, operating-system

How do document databases like MongoDB perform bulk writes efficiently? Given a large-sized JSON data that needs to be written onto the disk, how would a database parse the JSON and write it on the disk efficiently?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/

Comment: I don't know about MongoDB but there's no way to accelerate writing a file to a disk. Databases are more about data structures and accelerating access to them than about accelerating a file operation. The file operation is managed by the OS and is a system call. It cannot be accelerated much. If you want to know how databases work, learn about computer science and data structures.